# Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String' in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, http, fetch-api

I've been working on a quotes app that fetches data from a rest api, and displays each quote at a time randomly in the center of the screen with a press of a button. But can't quite get it right

I have made a method which fetches the json data, which is fetchQuotesData(), and it stores the unprocessed json in QuotesData. This is later converted into a list as QuotesList.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List QuotesList = [];
  var _data;
  var c;

  final url = "https://type.fit/api/quotes";

  fetchQuoteData() async {
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
    final QuotesData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      QuotesList = QuotesData;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchQuoteData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/pic/image4.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6), BlendMode.darken)
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Center(
           // Use future builder and DefaultAssetBundle to load the local JSON file
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: fetchQuoteData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              _data = snapshot.data.toString();
              var range = new Random();
              c = range.nextInt(_data.length);
              return Ui_Card(c);
              },
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          color: Colors.indigo.shade900,
           child: Container(
             margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0,right: 40.0),
             child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  tooltip:'Random Quotes',
                  icon: Icon(Icons.format_quote_outlined) ,
                  iconSize: 40,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: (){
                    HapticFeedback.heavyImpact();
                    setState(() {

                    });
                    },
                ),
              ],
             ),
           ),
         ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget Ui_Card(index){
    return new Container(
      child:  Center(
        child: Column(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
         children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
              child: Text(_data[c]['text'],
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Raleway-Italic',
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,),
                textScaleFactor: 2.0,)
          ),
              Text(_data[c]['author'],
                style:TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'Raleway-Bold',
                    fontSize: 18.0
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
         ],
       ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

I am suspecting some errors in the builder, or snapshot data, but not sure where I'm stuck

Comment: Welcome. I'll recommend you to give a look at the Dart language tour to understand more about this OOP language https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour Dart is a strongly type language and you need to specify the type/class of your variables in order to make things work. I'll also suggest you to post your debug console with the error and line

Answer (score 0):

As the comment on your question mentions, Dart is a strongly typed language. When you use 'var' you're relying on type inference to figure out the type you want for the variable. I've only been using Dart for about a year, but in my experience so far I try to never use 'var' because it can result in harder-to-debug error messages. Also if you set your variable types the linter seems to be better at picking up type mismatches.

```
var _data;
...
_data = snapshot.data.toString();
```

Above you set _data equal to a String.

```
child: Text(_data[c]['text'],
```

Here you are trying to access it as something else - maybe a `List<Map<String,String>>` or a `Map<int, Map<String,String>>`

My hunch is your error message is coming from ['text']. Maybe _data's inferred type can take a two-dimensional int index. The characters of a Dart string can be accessed with an int index - i.e. string[0] is the first character, but it returns an int, and int isn't an indexed type AFAIK, so I don't know what Dart is doing with your second index dimension that wants an int. I suspect if you change it to an int - i.e. `_data[0][0]` you'll get a different error message.

Try defining _data as the type you want it to be, then see if the linter shows the error in your source or you get a more descriptive error message.

Comment: Later, I have tried storing the json file as an offline file into the asset folder, and then removed fetchQuoteApp() class and all its methods to fetch, retrieve and store the json data from rest api. Now the code looks something like this,

Comment: `child: FutureBuilder(
            future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/json/q.json'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              _data = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
              var range = new Random();
              c = range.nextInt(_data.length);
              return Ui_Card(c);
              },
          ),`

Comment: with all other codes remaining the same. Now, the app is working as expected. Can you show me the right way to fetch the json data 'from a rest api', then randomly display quotes from that data with a press of a button

Comment: json.decode returns a Map<String,dynamic>, so when you want to use a value you usually need to cast it to the type you want. If you have `_data = json.decode('{"mylabel": "myvalue"}')`, and want to get the value of "mylabel", which is a String, you would `String mystring = _data["mylabel"] as String`  ... the `as String` tells Dart you want the `dynamic` type value held in _data as a `String` type, then you can do String stuff with it. If you have a json file with sub-objects and you want to fill out a class, the decoded json will be `Map<String,dynamic>` and you have to manually convert. hth